# Does a fd pointer get incremented when I use it to read() or write() AND how can the incrementation be controlled?

Tags: c, buffer, system-calls, file-descriptor, read-write

I'm attempting to read a line from a file and return a pointer to the beginning of the next line but I don't understand what's happening to the fd when I use it to read 10 chars at a time. I'm only able to use read, write, open and malloc.

Example *file.txt* (with `\n` being shown explicitly):

```
Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.\n
Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.\n
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n
```

*main.c*:

```
int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
int fd2 = open("oneline.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

read(fd, buffer, 10);
write(fd2, &buffer, 10);
```

1) Would `fd` now be pointing to the 11th character of `file.txt` and `fd2` at the EOF for `oneline.txt`?

---

Continued *main.c* example:

```
int newline = 0, found = 0;
while(found == 0)
{
    read(fd, buffer, 10);
    for(int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n' || i < 10; i++)
    {
        newline++;
        if(buffer[i] == '\n')
            found = 1;
    }
}
```

If `fd` is pointing to the 41st char in `file.txt` (the while loop ran 4 times and the '\n' is the 38th char). The value for the integer `newline` is equal to 38.

2) How can I get the fd to point to the 39th char which is just after the '\n' character?

Comment: If you know any good tutorials for working with file descriptors in C, please send a link.

Comment: Fyi, `read(fd, &buffer, 10);` is wrong. That should be `read(fd, buffer, 10);` . Your code is blasting over the pointer itself, not the memory it points to, thereby losing the allocation of the previous code line (the malloc) to the ether (and thus a memory leak), whilst invoking *undefined behavior* if the amount of data actually read is larger than the size of a pointer. Similar issue, but the opposite order, for `write(fd2, &buffer, 10);`.

Comment: the `fd` does NOT change.  The `fd` is an index into an array of file descriptors.  That array is kept by the OS.  Each file descriptor contains all the info about the file (when the file is open).  Each file descriptor is a `struct`.  In general, you never need to know the details about the contents of the file descriptor struct.

Comment: regarding: `int fd2 = open("oneline.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);`  when creating a file, should include the third parameter, which is often a simple octal number, that indicates the permissions of the file

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);`  the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect. Suggest removing that expression.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. If not successful, call `perror()` to let the user know the problem, the cleanup and exit the program

Comment: OT: when calling `open()`, always check >=0 the returned value to assure the operation was successful, if not successful, call `perror()` to let the user know, then clean up and exit the program

Comment: regarding: `read(fd, &buffer, 10);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successfil.

Comment: @user3629249 I wrote that code quickly just for demonstration. I now understand that there's a _file offset_ of some sort associated with the fd and that the fd struct contains a `file *pointer`. I will read up on the permissions octal parameter, thanks for all the tips. Do you think I could decrement the file *pointer after the while loop with another while loop like so: `while((newline % 10) < 11) { fd.file--; newline++; }` which would decrement `fd.file` thrice since newline = 38 leaving `fd.file` at the '\n', right?

Comment: `fd` is an `int`, not a `struct` of any sort. There is no `fd.file`. The kernel does keep a `struct` corresponding to the value of your `int` behind the scenes, but you have absolutely no direct access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about the *file offset*. To your first question, yes, you're correct about where the offsets are at that point. To your second question, you can use [`lseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) to move the offset back. To go back 2 characters, you'd do `lseek(fd, -2, SEEK_CUR)`.

Comment: Is there any way to maybe move it without lseek? Should I create a duplicate of the fd and then when I encounter the '\n', increment the duplicate to that point?

Comment: @ntruter42 `lseek` is the way to move it. Why don't you want to use that? And no, `dup`ing it won't work, since duplicates of an FD all share the same offset.